# ngenter and ngleave classes doesn't seem to get added

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to fadein and fadeout div's using nganimate via the ngshow. But the animation doesn't happen. What am i doing wrong here?

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <button ng-click="showMailOn()">Opt1</button>
    <button ng-click="showMailOff()">Opt2</button>
    <div ng-animate="'email-profile-option'" ng-show="showMailContent()" >
        <span>Content1</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-animate="'email-profile-option'" ng-hide="showMailContent()" >
        <span>Content2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngAnimate']); 
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

    var mailOpt = true;
    $scope.showMailOn = function() {
      mailOpt = true;
    }
    $scope.showMailOff = function() {
      mailOpt = false;
    }
    $scope.showMailContent = function() {
      return mailOpt;
    }
})
```

CSS

```
.email-profile-option.ng-enter, .email-profile-option.ng-leave {
         -webkit-transition:all linear 0.3s;
          -moz-transition:all linear 0.3s;
          -ms-transition:all linear 0.3s;
          -o-transition:all linear 0.3s;
          transition:all linear 0.3s;
      }

      .email-profile-option.ng-enter{}
      .email-profile-option.ng-enter-active{opacity: 1;}
      .email-profile-option.ng-leave{}
      .email-profile-option.ng-leave-active{opacity: 0;}
```

Plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/d9kpOYYVAovO7aj5HIZl?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

The directive `ngshow` uses `ng-hide` classes: `ng-hide-add`, `ng-hide-remove`  and the active classes as `ng-hide-add-active` and `ng-hide-remove-active`.

Also you should use the `class` selector of your html element :

```
<div  ng-hide="showMailContent()" >
        <span class="animation">Content2</span>
 </div>
```

And in the `CSS`:

```
animation.ng-hide-add{
/* Your exit animation here */
}
animation.ng-hide-remove{
/* your enter animation here */
}
```

See the [ng-show](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow#usage_animations) page for reference.